# I got an error, error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)

Tags: kubernetes, aws-cli, kubectl, amazon-eks

I got an error while accessing the aws-eks.

error msg:
`error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)`

I set my aws account on loca by using aws-cli.

```
aws configure
...

aws sts get-caller-identity
>>
{
    "UserId": "AIDA55PSGUGIDUYKM7YRI",
    "Account": "956675039632",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::956675039632:user/test-eks-windows"
}
```

And I ran the command below.
`aws eks --region ap-northeast-2 update-kubeconfig --name test-eks-cluster`

But, I had the error msg above.

Here is my aws account policy.
`-AdministratorAccess`

What's wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `aws-auth` configmap and give permissions to your user.   How did you create the cluster? if through terraform or CLI, you need to add your user or role to the configmap. You should use the user or role that was used to create the EKS cluster as that user/role will have permissions to K8s cluster and then update the `aws-auth` configmap and add other users or roles... Edit configmap by running

```
kubectl edit configmap aws-auth -n kube-system
```

and add the following mapUsers field or add a role in mapRole field

```
  mapUsers: |
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:user/test-eks-windows
      username: test-eks-windows
      groups:
      - system:master
```

Comment: I created the cluster on website.

Comment: sry, I am a new user to aws-eks and kubernets.

Comment: On, my cluster policy,   
installed AmazonEksClusterPolicy, AmazonEKSVPCResourceControl

And my entity.   

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "eks.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: you should use the same user that you used to create the EKS cluster, and get the kubeconfig from that user, and then run kubectl edit configmap aws-auth -n kube-system   and then add your user in mapUsers field

Comment: updated answer to add command to edit configmap and add mapUsers field